# Getting the value of a slider in Jquerymobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-slider

I am unable to get this to work in jquerymobile I am getting null on the weightvalue variable :

JS

```
$("#submitWeight").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    submitWeight(e);
}); 

function submitWeight(e){

    var weightMonth = $("#selectMonth option:selected").text();
    var weightValue = $("#sliderWeight").slider( "option", "value");

    alert("Done");
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="range" name="slider" id="sliderWeight" value="60" min="0" max="100" data-theme="c" >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/s33tX/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    alert($("#sliderWeight").val());
});
```

Comment: I thot I tried this before but I tried this again and it worked. Thanks a lot